# Interactive grid - populate a field on insert automatically

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a records table with the following columns :

```
Record_ID - primary key
Item_ID
Record_Text
Record_Status
Create_Date
```

Each item can have multiple records. I display the table data in an interactive grid. The grid only displays data for one item at a time. `Item_ID` is a hidden field on the page `P2_ITEM_ID`

On my grid `Record_ID` and `Item_ID` are hidden field, I only display `Record_Text`, Record_Status(a `checkbox` for `Active/Inactive`), and `Create_Date` as display only field. When insert is done, primary key is generated automatically, `Create_Date` is populated with a trigger, so the only fields that
need to be supplied are `Item_ID`, `Record_Text` and `Record_Status`. When **Add Row** is clicked, the user populated `Record_Text` and checks the `checkbox` for `Record_Status`. But how do I populate `Item_ID` for each row automatically from a hidden variable?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to do something in a column that is not editable in IG. Maybe is possible, but I don't know. If is not possible, maybe you can create your pl/sql manually, in this pl/sql I think do you have access to the value of the item. Check this post: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3937159

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4035826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish that by setting a default value for the Item_ID column of my grid to type `Item` and the Item field I set to the hidden field P2_Item_ID